# convert a list of string_words into a list of lists

Tags: python-3.x

So I want to convert a list of strings "words", into a list of lists.
This list comes in a result of ssh communication, that gives me an output of strings, like a text. After that i use "re.findall" to get the strings that i want, and do append to an empty list.

```
macs = ['2c:31:24', '00:38:df']

macs_list = list(macs)
```

So the result that i have is this:

```
['2c:31:24', '00:38:df']
```

when i tried to convert into a list of lists the result is this one:

```
[['2','c'.':','3','1',':','2','4'],['0','0',':','3','8',':'.'d','f']
```

what i expect, is this:

```
[['2c:31:24'], ['00:38:df']]
```

Comment: `[[i] for i in macs]` ?

Comment: You can also do this `list(map(list, macs)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works[based on Rakesh suggestion]

```
macs = ['2c:31:24', '00:38:df']
all_rows = [[row] for row in macs]  
print(all_rows)
```

output:

```
[['2c:31:24'], ['00:38:df']]
```

Comment: Thank you all, it works bur exists one problem.
If i have more elements it will not work.
for example:

    macs = ['2c:31:24', '00:38:df'], [ac:32:22', '00:38:df', 3d:31:21']

    all_rows = [[row] for row in macs]

    print(all_rows)

result:

    [[[2c:31:24'], ['00:38:df']], [ac:32:22', '00:38:df', 3d:31:21'], [[2c:31:24'], ['00:38:df']], 
    [ac:32:22', '00:38:df', 3d:31:21'], [[2c:31:24'], ['00:38:df']], [ac:32:22', '00:38:df', 
    3d:31:21']]]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, it works but exists one problem.
If i have more elements it will not work.
for example:

```
macs = ['2c:31:24', '00:38:df'], [ac:32:22', '00:38:df', 3d:31:21']

all_rows = [[row] for row in macs]

print(all_rows)
```

result:

```
[[[2c:31:24'], ['00:38:df']], [ac:32:22', '00:38:df', 3d:31:21'], [[2c:31:24'], ['00:38:df']], 
[ac:32:22', '00:38:df', 3d:31:21'], [[2c:31:24'], ['00:38:df']], [ac:32:22', '00:38:df', 
3d:31:21']]]
```